# RN Navigation deep linking is ignoring Linking config

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am trying to use deep-linking in my expo & react native prod app, but no matter how many times I read the documentation, nothing seems to work.

`LinkingConfiguration.js`

```js
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

const prefix = Linking.createURL('/'); 
// this creates a link with the correct scheme, whether it be exp:// or the app's prod scheme

export default {
    prefixes: [
        prefix
    ],
    config: {
        screens: {
            Authenticated: {
                screens: {
                    ...
                    JoinFromLinkScreen: {
                        path: "invite/:inviteCode",
                        parse: {
                            inviteCode: (inviteCode) => String(inviteCode),
                        },
                    }
                },
            },
            Unauthenticated: {
               ...
            },
            NotFound: "*",
        },
    },
};
```

I am using this linking configuration in the following manner.

`Index.jsx`:

```js
import LinkingConfiguration...

export default Navigation = () => {
...
return (
        <NavigationContainer
            linking={LinkingConfiguration}
        >
            <RootNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const RootNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            { some_conditions && <Stack.Screen name="Authenticated" component={AuthenticatedNavigator} /> }
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

The `AuthenticatedNavigator` is a `BottomTabNavigator` with several tabs on the screen. I can guarantee that the `JoinFromLinkScreen` is accessible by the tab navigator.

What am I doing wrong? How should I edit the `LinkingConfiguration` above such that navigating to `scheme://invite/:inviteCode` actually brings up the correct `JoinFromLinkScreen`?

*Edit*: For clarification, this does not work for either my production scheme (denoted `scheme://`) or the expo scheme `exp://`